# shoutcast v2 and whmsonic

Tags: shoutcast

So here is the issue I face, the current WHMSonic only supports version 1 of shoutcast as many of you know shoutcast has moved to a better system and are now on version 2.0 I would like to use WHMSonic and send stations to Shoutcast V2 however it seems that this is not allowed.

So is there away to fix this or is there another WHMSonic that will offer support for shoutcast version 2

Comment: What features are you using in SHOUTcast 2 Beta?

Comment: @Brad the main feature is the fact we only need one shoutcast server running not 3 of them

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here, it does support Shoutcast 2:

[image: WHMSonic]

Try this:
List Manage my radio--->Change Radio system to shoutcast 2 and then Click here:
[image: Enter server Login]

after Create the “Authhash” for Shoutcast v2 servers, use this tutorial, to make the radio public: [Authhash Tutorial](https://www.internet-radio.com/community/threads/creating-the-%E2%80%9Cauthhash%E2%80%9D-for-shoutcast-v2-servers.21409/)

Note: i just notice now the date of the question, but i think the answer is still useful as it take me a lot of time to find this information.